# Error 500 Internal Server Error Whenever I Deploy BlogEngine.NET To Remote Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, blogengine.net

Each time I deploy BlogEngine on a remote server on IIS, I get `Error 500 - Internal Server Error`, anytime I try creating a new post. I have followed procedures on deploying BlogEngine on IIS ([here](http://www.rtur.net/blog/page/BlogEngineNET-Deployment-Guide)), i have created the NETWORK SERVICE property and given it permissions in the App_Data folder. I even gave permissions to the IIS_USR property on the remote server.

I try making a post on BlogEngine, I get an `Error making post` toastr message. Whereas this same project works without any hindrance on my local computer.

I narrowed the post action to postEditController.js, to the $scope.save() function but I'm not getting any stack trace whatsoever in Inspect Element.

Comment: Have you checked you IIS server logs?

Comment: I have checked them. It just states Error 500. No other detailed information.

Comment: Maybe enabling debug level logs should help you find the error at least.

Comment: Please how do I do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging

Comment: Couldn't find the Advanced Logging feature on IIS manager. Tried downloading the extension but i keep getting redirected to some microsoft help page. I tried using Event Viewer, but I wasn't seeing any error.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 - Internal Server Error usually pops up when you are using incorrect version of .net framework. Check the application pool is 4.0 or 4.5 and app pool is running.